# How to convert CameraInfo sensor msgs to Images?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is there any function for converting CameraInfo sensor messages to images. I'm aware of CvBridge library but it seems to me like it only works for Image sensor messages. I appreciate your help!

---

Edit:

Sorry if you misunderstood me. Video was recorded from the camera, but the .bag wasn't recorded using Image msg type. It's structured like this:

```
some header
     <Preface Index>    // preface frame index
     <Message Data> // first frame record
....
     <Message Data> // last frame record
<Index Data>    // index of all records in the previous chunk
<Connection>    // connection specs
<Chunk Info>    // additional chunk info
```

So, when I type rosbag info in command line, I get only CameraInfo msg type recognized, but that msgs are probably containing our special format.

So, what I'm then interested in is how to access/view the content of these msgs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302472/how-to-convert-camerainfo-sensor-msgs-to-images?/) by [latida](https://answers.ros.org/users/35677/latida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-09-05**:
sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.msg contains only information for a camera such as camera, projection and distortion matrices. It does not contain the images so  you should use CvBridge to convert ROS images (sensor_msgs/Image) into OpenCV (cv::Mat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is there any function for converting CameraInfo sensor messages to images

[CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) msgs do not encode images, so this is impossible and no such function exists.

---

Edit:

> my .bag file contains only CameraInfo msg type

So only those messages, no other messages?

> but the video that's recorded from the camera has a special format in which it's stored into

But not in the bag then? That's at least what you write in the previous sentence.

> Is there a way at least to access the message to view raw string format?

Messages are not always strings, especially not images, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

---

Edit2:

> Video was recorded from the camera, but the .bag wasn't recorded using Image msg type. It's structured like this:
>
> ```
> some header
> ```

```
     <Preface Index>    // preface frame index
     <Message Data> // first frame record
....
     <Message Data> // last frame record
<Index Data>    // index of all records in the previous chunk
<Connection>    // connection specs
<Chunk Info>    // additional chunk info
```

Is this the structure of the bag, or data from the camera?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [latida](https://answers.ros.org/users/35677/latida/) on 2018-09-05**:
Thanks, the problem is that my .bag file contains only CameraInfo msg type, but the video that's recorded from the camera has a special format in which it's stored into. Is there a way at least to access the message to view raw string format?